# Как посмотреть все доступные поля класса, который наследует другой класс?

Tags: visual-studio

Есть класс A, который наследует класс B, который наследует класс C и тд...

Мне нужно посмотреть все доступные свойства для класса А.

Пока я вижу 2 варианта:

1. Просматривать реализацию каждого класса по очереди
2. При использовании при помощи InteliSence

Думаю, не нужно объяснять, почему оба этих варианта жутко неудобны. Может есть более простой способ? Хочу видеть все доступные свойства для класса А в одном окне без необходимости вносить временные изменения в код с целью открыть меню InteliSence.